# c++ and xml binding simpletype

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xsd, codesynthesis

These days I want to learn XML data binding for C++, so I found a library to generate C++ code from an XSD file. I tested the Hello World example and succeeded to create two files, the header file and the C++ file. The library is called **CodeSynthesis XSD**.

for more information:

[www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/)

but I remark that this library only generates complex types (classes, enumeration, union ...), and my question is how I could generate simple types, for example:

```
int data ; 
float data ;
```

because i googled for a few hours without finding any solution or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try xsd:int and xsd:float instead of int and float.